# Postgres changes query plan for prepared statement to something poor after multiple invocations

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, explain, prepared-statement

Postgres 13.4

I have a prepared statement that is similar to this:

```sql
PREPARE my_statement AS 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (normalized_name = $1 OR distinct_normalized_names @> array['$1']) AND name_matchable = TRUE
ORDER BY name ASC, disambiguation ASC NULLS FIRST, official ASC, release_date DESC, product_code ASC, language ASC LIMIT 1
```

I have a BTree index on `name`, `normalized_name`, `name_matchable`, and a GIST index on `distinct_normalized_names`.

I also have an BTree index on the ordering portion of this query, mostly for purposes not related to the prepared statement `name ASC, disambiguation ASC NULLS FIRST, official ASC, release_date DESC, product_code ASC, language ASC`

When I prepare this statement and run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on it, I see a reasonable plan and this prepared statement executes very fast:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE my_statement('example');
```

```
Limit  (cost=105.26..105.26 rows=1 width=1706) (actual time=0.056..0.057 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=105.26..105.28 rows=48 width=1706) (actual time=0.055..0.056 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: name, disambiguation NULLS FIRST, official, release_date DESC, product_code, language
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=10.16..105.21 rows=48 width=1706) (actual time=0.043..0.044 rows=0 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((normalized_name = 'example'::text) OR (distinct_normalized_names @> '{example}'::text[]))
              Filter: name_matchable
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=10.16..10.16 rows=48 width=0) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_products_on_normalized_name  (cost=0.00..2.11 rows=20 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (normalized_name = 'example'::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_products_on_distinct_normalized_names_gin  (cost=0.00..8.04 rows=28 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (distinct_normalized_names @> '{example}'::text[])
Planning Time: 1.624 ms
Execution Time: 0.157 ms
```

However, if I invoke the prepared statement around ten times or more, Postgres suddenly switches the plan to something much worse, using a field I did not WHERE-clause on and it remains there until I `DEALLOCATE` the prepared statement.

```sql
-- If run this statement 10 or so times, then the plan below is provided
EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE my_statement('example');
```

```
Limit  (cost=53.67..104.57 rows=1 width=1706) (actual time=763.908..763.909 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=53.67..87248.70 rows=1713 width=1706) (actual time=763.906..763.907 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: name, disambiguation NULLS FIRST, official, release_date DESC, product_code, language
        Presorted Key: name
        Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 25kB  Peak Memory: 25kB
        ->  Index Scan using index_products_on_name on products  (cost=0.08..87228.90 rows=1713 width=1706) (actual time=763.888..763.888 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (name_matchable AND ((normalized_name = $1) OR (distinct_normalized_names @> ARRAY[$1])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 338960
Planning Time: 0.015 ms
Execution Time: 764.064 ms
```

As you can see, the total time ballooned from ~3ms to 760ms. This prepared statement is used heavily, so this isn't ideal. I can watch this problem happen in real time on a database under load by `PREPARE`ing the statement, running it about 10 times, then seeing the performance plummet and the `EXPLAIN` change.

It looks like Postgres is suddenly deciding that the prepared statement should use a different index and a much different strategy, but this is worse performance.

I was able to work around this issue by not using a prepared statement at all, and I don't see the issue occur if I use raw SQL, even after repeated invocations.

Why does Postgres decide to change the plan for the statement after repeated use?

Comment: How much of your data has `name_matchable = TRUE` and how much on your typical searched rows have it? Maybe you could try creating indexes with either `name_matchable = TRUE` as a filter (partial index) or `name_matchable` as first field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks the generic plan you show (with the `$1` in it) will be slightly faster than the custom plan (with the actual value in it), 104.57 vs 105.26.  So after running a number of custom plans and thinking there is no benefit, it doesn't think it is worthwhile making a new custom plan each time. Of course the estimate is way off, but the estimate is what it has to go by.

You can `set plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan` to prevent it from doing this.  Of course if you set this globally, it might make other things worse, as now it will be re-planning queries all the time even when the generic plan is perfectly fine, and planning can sometimes be a bottleneck.  But since you have evidence that using generic plans is actually a problem for you, and no evidence that using re-planning would be, I would just go make the change (documenting why) unless it is easy to tell your client not to prepare this particular query.

Comment: I’ve already switched away from using a prepared statement in this case, but I’m also trying to understand why it switched to such a bad plan or how I can improve it for next time. 

If I write a query, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` it, and I see a good plan, I don’t like the idea that by putting it inside a prepared statement, sometime in the future Postgres might just decide to blow up the plan and make it a worse by more than a factor of 100. 

Is this something I can improve with more column statistics or extended statistics perhaps?

Comment: It thinks there will be 1713 rows on average in the generic case, and for all we know that might be correct.  Maybe there is *some* value of for $1 for which it returns a huge number of rows.  Or maybe there isn't--we can't tell from the info here.  For the scalar, you could look in pg_stats to see if ndistinct is about accurate.  For the array column, I'm not really sure what to look at, maybe you could show all of the pg_stats row corresponding to that column.

Comment: ", I don’t like the idea that by putting it inside a prepared statement, sometime in the future Postgres might just decide to blow up"  Then I think `plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan` is exactly for you.  The increased planning time is at least more predictable than the rare execution blow-up.